# How to install Python newt or snack in Mac OS X for byobu

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, python, byobu

I've installed byobu in Mac OS X 10.6.5. It will start, (i.e. it will start a screen session) but in order to run byobu-config and probably in order to do some other things I need a module called snack which apparently is part of python newt.

`pip search newt` and `pip search snack` return no results. newt and snack aren't in MacPorts or Brew either.

I haven't found anything online in my searching with respect to installing newt on Mac OS X.

Has anyone else been able to install byobu and newt in Mac OS X?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try,

```
sudo port install libnewt
```

After that, you may need to add /opt/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages to PYTHONPATH as follows,

```
export PYTHONPATH=/opt/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/
```

or

```
setenv PYTHONPATH /opt/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/
```

Comment: Any way to do this with homebrew?

Comment: You want `brew install newt`. Should happen by default with an up-to-date `byobu` formula.

Comment: @jrhorn424 newt is installed for me, but I still cant find snack

Comment: I don't recall how I got this to work, but I do know that I reinstalled `brew python` and `brew python3` at some point, and I also removed the system and brew python executables from my search path. Very likely re-installed `byobu` as well. Have you tried `brew install [newt|byobu] --with-python`? I don't know the spec for formulas well enough to tell which actually needs that flag.

Answer (score 0):

There's currently an annoying issue where the `newt` Homebrew package is not correctly building the Python extensions, see [Homebrew/homebrew-core PR#37479: Fix newt python detection on mojave](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/37479). Either build the `newt` package from that PR, or have a look at the discussion on that PR for a workaround.

Essentially, it boils down to adding a patch similar to this to the Homebrew formula for `newt`:

```
     inreplace "configure", "ls /usr/include/python*/Python.h", "find /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/ -name 'Python.h'"
```

... or building `newt` from the latest source code and running `./configure ... --with-python=python2.7` (why Python2.7? I didn't check myself if `byobu-config` was Python3 compliant, but the [Arch Linux AUR PKGBUILD](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=byobu) specifies Python2 as a dependency.).